# Why don't we use the same utensils for milk and meat if the food is cold

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, meat-and-milk

If I have designated utensils for cold foods such as salad, or cold salami and cheese. What is the problem of using the same utensils for both milk and meat, since there is no bliya because both are cold.

Comment: Who said there is a problem?

Comment: I'm not looking up sources right now and so can't say in detail but problems that can crop up are (a) washing with hot water, (b) _dochaka d'sakina_, and (c) mixing up your utensils and using the wrong ones with hot foods also.

Comment: Also Shuman and dvar charif

Comment: Oh, and _kovesh_.

Answer (score 4):

Dr. Haym Soloveitchik notes this anomaly (that really there's no need to have separate dishware for cold foods) in the beginning of his famous essay, [Rupture and Reconstruction](https://www.scribd.com/document/92641274/Soloveitchik-Haym-Rupture-and-Reconstruction) (second paragraph): "The simple fact is that the traditional Jewish kitchen, transmitted from mother to daughter over generations, has been immeasurably and unrecognizably amplified beyond all halakhic requirements". However, I think there's good reason for this, as one's liable to make a mistake pretty easily, especially since today food is dishes are washed with hot water (as pointed out in the comments).

Comment: "[T]oday food is dishes are washed with hot water"?

Comment: @SethJ yeah sorry. Also I should add that got water might not necessarily create an issue since most people (that I know) use soap with the hot water

Answer (score 1):

See Sefer Pischei Halacha Kitzur Hilchos Kashrus (excellent sefer for the basics of kashrus)perek 1:20 brings the Shulchan Aruch 89:4 that forbids cutting bread with a meat knife by a dairy seudah and the opposite and the Rishonim were machmir when it came to cutting cheese even when cold with a meat knife .The reason for all this is because sometimes the fattiness of the food is left on the knife(see the Tur).  However ,if you don't have another knife then one can do neitzah bkarka 10 times(Aruch Hashulchan seif 16 and Chochmas Adam 40:14 hold a kinuach is good enough when it comes to bread[some hold steel wool is like neitzah].

The custom of klal Yisroel is to have two separate flatware for meat and dairy(Aruch Hashulchan 16) so one does not mix them up,and the siman is always on the dairy not meat (Rama)

Comment: It is no longer the custom that the siman is always on the dairy not meat.

Comment: True,just quoting the text

Comment: If anything ppl became more machmir and put simabim on both

Comment: @DoubleAA, I'm not sure you're right. I seem to recall from my camp days in the '80s that the dairy utensils, when similar to the meat ones, were punctured, and the explanation (for choice of which ones to puncture) was that that was an old custom.

Comment: @msh210 It's no longer the custom of klal Yisroel, as many do not have that custom. Perhaps some small segments of it do. Perhaps some have the opposite custom too.

Answer (score 0):

The Rama discusses a similar case of using glass for both meat and dairy. Even though bliyot are not possible, as they do not go into the glass, nevertheless the minhag is to be machmir because it will be confusing. `Using the same utensils should be even more chamur than glass where there is no possibility of bliyot.`

Comment: The Rama very likely thought that glass does have bliyos. Can you cite the Rama you refer to more precisely?

Comment: There's a mishna in מסכת חולין that says you could wrap meat and cheese in the same container or napkin, I will find it again but it's confusing why to be so stringent if the Mishnah seems to be very lenient

Comment: @DoubleAA its found in Shulchan Aruch [Orach Chaim 451:26]. The Shulchan aruch paskins that you can use it completely just by cleaning it off. The Rama was nervous about that.

Comment: @SamReinstein maybe that's only by Chometz on Pesach and not by baser and chalav.