# If cleaned between meals can the same knife be used for cold dairy and cold meat items?

Tags: halacha, meat-and-milk

If one thoroughly washes a knife between meals can the same knife be used to cut cold meat items and cold dairy items?

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36216/759

Answer (score 1):

See SA YD 89:4

> שולחן ערוך יורה דעה
> & rlm;..... אסור לחתוך גבינה אפילו צוננת בסכין שרגילין לחתוך בשר ....‏
>
> הגה: וכן להפך נמי אסור מיהו על ידי נעיצה בקרקע קשה שרי (ב"י בשם א"ח וכל בו) אבל כבר נהגו כל ישראל להיות להם שני סכינים ולרשום אחד מהם שיהא לו היכר ונהגו לרשום של חלב ואין לשנות מנהג ישראל: ‏

Rabbi Karo says that one may not cut cheese, even cold, with a knife that one uses to cut meat.

The Remo comments that the same applies the other way round (cut meat after cheese).

After pushing the knife into hard ground *(and cleaning it, I assume)*, it *(the cutting)* should be allowed, but the custom amongst all Israel is to have two knives *(one for meat and one for milk)* and to mark one of them so it should not be mistaken – and the custom is to mark the milky knife and one should not change from the Jewish custom.

So it seems that you cannot use the same slicer for cheese and meat.

Answer (score -2):

NO. even though it was cold there is a problem called "duchkei disakinei" which basically means  the (heat) of the friction from the cutting.
 see (פמ''ג מש''ז סק''ג that this can be a problem even if it is not a daver charif)
[This is all only in regard to lchatchilah-intending to purposely use in this manner, if one already accidently used for both there is much room to be meikel in most cases]

Comment: Source? maybe cleaning it thoroughly is enough, even though it's not a popular option?

Comment: That is only the case with a *davar charif* (something significantly sharp-tasting that was considered to have the ability to cause absorption of taste into certain utensils).

Comment: wrong. a daver charif would be a problem even with out duchina disakin according to most poskim

Comment: The Rama 89:4 says this is fine, though people generally don't do it.